# How to get timezone(offset from GMT) and convert to double in android

Tags: android

In my app I need to get the timezone, convert it to a double and add it with specific double data. I use following:

```
Double.parseDouble(Time.getCurrentTimezone())
```

Unfortunately this does not work properly. Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Double d = (double) (TimeZone.getTimeZone(Time.getCurrentTimezone()).getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

`Time.getCurrentTimezone()`returns the timezone id as a `String`, you have to use the `TimeZone` class to get at the offset, and you have to pass the current time, because the timezone offset depends on the exact instance in time, i.e. timezone offsets are not static.

The `getOffset()` method returns an `int` with the timezone offset in milliseconds. Not sure why exactly you need a `double` but you can just cast it.

If you want the offset in hours you could also do:

```
Double d = (TimeZone.getTimeZone(Time.getCurrentTimezone()).getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())) / (1000.0 * 60.0 * 60.0);
```

Also remember, not all timezone offsets are full hours.